# java - cannot find symbol - Class Arraylist

Tags: java

I keep getting the following error with my arraylist. Any help is appreciated

cannot find symbol - Class Arraylist

```
public class Bank
{
    private ArrayList<Account> accounts;


    /**
     * A bank starts without any accounts.
     */
    public Bank()
    {
    accounts = new Arraylist<Account>();
    }
```

Answer (score 21):

You need to add `import` declarations on class file header.

`ArrayList` is member of `java.util package`.

And, remember that Java is a **case sensitive** language. `ArrayList` is different from `Arraylist`

You should declare like following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Bank{
/*class content*/
}
```

Answer (score 12):

capitalize the L in ArrayList.

Answer (score 5):

Java is case-sensitive. I think the problem is in this line:

> accounts = new Arraylist();

It's "ArrayList" not Arraylist.

I hope to have been helpfull.

Comment: While that is certainly true, the case problem *was* mentioned three times in the previous responses, all dated over a year ago ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It's `ArrayList`, not `Arraylist`.  Case matters.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the line `import java.util.*` in header.

Comment: Please explain what additional insight this answer provides, especially in comparison to the older, upvoted answer by Andre Pastore. Discuss why importing less specifically is an advantage.